# Hold banner (Local Notification Alert) in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to hold **banner** (in *Local Notification*) just for 2 or 3 mins. Can we do this if yes then how. and Can i set programmatically local notification style for application.

**Banner**

[image]

I want to hold the banner or to hold text permanently on the notification bar

**Notification Bar**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

iOS notification Banner are setted up by the user and there are no Public API to have custom one for your application. Neither the hold time is global and shared through the system by all the applications. Think about a developer that set the banner hold time to a very big number ... what should happen? To keep the system consistent Apple chose to keep it private.

Notification center works in the same way and you can't access it. The notification center instead keep all notifications, I suppose, for infinite time ... just until the user decide to delete it pressing the little X.